# Derivative Of a function with respect to a different variable.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives, soft-question

Today in a standard calculus course in high school,i notice that our sir wrote :
$$\frac{d}{dx} \cos(2t)=\frac{d}{dt}(\cos2t).\frac{dx}{dt}$$
But i am supposed to write as :
say $u=\cos(2t)$
Then $$\frac{du}{dx}=\frac{d}{dt}(\cos2t).\frac{dt}{dx}$$
That's what the chain rule says :
Please explain which of these is right and explain.

Comment: Your version should be the right one. I guess he simply made a mistake.

Comment: @mrtaurho yeah i guess so...You know my heart beat was stopped nearly when i assume what if my foundation is so bad.Thanks buddy

Comment: I would like to add one point,here it should be, $t=f(x)$

Answer (score 2):

Yes, yours is correct clearly.
$$\frac{du}{dx} = \frac{du}{dt}\cdot\frac{dt}{dx}$$
This way, the $dt$’s balance, leaving you with $\frac{du}{dx}$.